# Advantages of using prime number as interval during a shell sort?

Tags: sorting

As I understand it's best practice to always use a prime number during a shell sort for its interval. Why is this the case?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Why do you think that's best practice?  Where did you read that?  Also, what research have you done?  Have you read [the Wikipedia article on shell sort]()https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort and gap sequences for shell sort, and followed up on the references there?  Those resources don't seem to agree with your contention.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what you've found so far.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I think Shellsort doesn't work if you always use prime numbers. If you don't use 1 as the last interval, you'll find it very, very hard to prove that Shellsort actually works.

Answer (score 2):

It is still an open question what the best gap sequence for shell sort would be; and what the performance of shell sort would be with an optimal sequence.

The "holy grail" for comparison based sorts is O(lg(n!)) ~= n*lg(n) -n performance.
No one has ever found a gap sequence for shell sort that achieves that.

Here's what we do know-
1= the last gap must always be 1 (insertion sort)
2= there should be no more than lg(n) -1 gaps
(thus the lg(n) -1 gap is always going to be 1)
3= the gaps should at least be relatively prime to each other.
4= the gaps should be between a factor of 2 or 3 of each other
5= the gaps can not be expressed by a closed form math formula if you want worst case performance better than O(n*lg^2(n)) or O(n^(3/2))

Thus using just primes closest to (n/2)^i for the first lg(n)-2 passes can be a very good choice, but
a= we as of yet can not prove such a gap sequence would be optimal, and
b= figuring out what the gap sequence is for any given size of data set is non trivial if all of our gaps are primes.

Comment: This looks like a nice answer. A minor drawback, "primes closest to $(n/2)^i$" only makes sense when $i=1$.

Comment: "primes closest to (n/2)^i for the first lg(n) -2 passes" was intended to mean p(n/2), p(n/4), p(n/8), ... p(n/2)^(lg(n)-2)   So for n= 2^10= 1024, the gaps are 509, 257, 127, 61, 31, 17, 7, 3, 1

Comment: You meant primes closest to $n/2^i$ or $\frac n{2^i}$, didn't you?